# use for loop to iterate through Linq group result set

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I have a Linq group result set called **myGroup**. myGroup is a type of

**IGrouping < String,myObject >**

I am trying to iterate through this via a **for** loop.

Currently, I can do something like this:

```
foreach (var item in group)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Id);
}
```

How can I achieve the same thing using for loop?

I attempt doing something like below:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < myGroup.Count(); i++)
         {
          // Now How can I access the current myGroup Item?
          //I DO NOT have ElementAt() property in myGroup.
          myGroup.ElementAt(i).Id // THIS IS NOT POSSIBLE
         }
```

but I don't know how can I access myGroup current Element in the for loop

Comment: Could you please be more clear about your requirement?

Comment: Why you want to move to `for` specifically?

Comment: @un-lucky, I edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @Prajwal, I guess there is a reason for it, otherwise I wouldn't post this here :) Thanks anyway.

Comment: Why is that not possible to use ElementAt()? Any errors?

Comment: @IDeveloper, I just don't have the ElementAt() in my IntelliSense :)

Comment: @Benjamin can you please post all your `using` statements?

Comment: @Benjamin did you add the using System.Linq?

Comment: Sorry,  my bad. It was due to using statement. Thanks @IDeveloper

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a working sample using ElementAt():

```
public class Thing
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Item { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foos = new List<Thing>
        {
            new Thing { Category = "Fruit", Item = "Apple" },
            new Thing { Category = "Fruit", Item = "Orange" },
            new Thing { Category = "Fruit", Item = "Banana" },
            new Thing { Category = "Vegetable", Item = "Potato" },
            new Thing { Category = "Vegetable", Item = "Carrot" }
        };

        var group = foos.GroupBy(f => f.Category).First();

        for (int i = 0; i < group.Count(); i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(group.ElementAt(i).Item); //works great
        }
    }
}
```